# How should I organise code so that I can see instances of a class in multiple pages of a WinJS Store App?

Tags: javascript, windows-store-apps, winjs

(examples taken from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967793.aspx)

If I have the robot class stored after my default.js file on my main page.

```
// robot.js
(function () {
     var Robot = WinJS.Class.define(function (name) {
            this.name = name;
        },
        { modelName: "" },
        { harmsHumans: false, obeysOrders: true }
    );

    WinJS.Namespace.define("Robotics", {
        Robot: Robot
    });
})();
```

And in page1.js, I create an instance of the robot.

```
// page1.js
var myRobot = new Robotics.Robot("Sam");
var harm = Robotics.Robot.harmsHumans;
```

What is the best way to access the myRobot instance from page2.js?

```
// page2.js
console.log(myRobot.name);
```

I've looked at WinJS namespaces but all the examples i've seen show instances being accessed from the same page.

Should I look to store the instance in a storage of some kind?

Answer (score 0):

A WinJS namespace simply adds the namespace name (e.g. Robotics) as a variable in the global namespace, so anything you place within a namespace (e.g. Robotics.Robot) is accessible from that root name from any other place in your code. This means you can just add another member like robotInstance: null to your namespace definition in robot.js, and then in page1.js set Robotics.robotInstance = myRobot; . page2.js can then just access Robotics.robotInstance, no problem.

Bottom line is that WinJS namespaces are just a convention to keep the global namespace organized and uncluttered, but otherwise it's just global variables. There's no magic.